# Subsequent events not triggering in while loop

Tags: events, loops, labview

I have a **MAIN VI** and a **SUB VI** which communicate events through **control refnum**. flow of events is as follows.

1) **sub vi** changes a value of its control and this event is handled in the **main vi**(this works).

2) **main vi** in response to the event changes one of its control and triggers an event from the event handler itself which is handled in the **subvi event handler**.(this also works).

The first phase is over. Now the main vi is running a while loop and the sub vi is running a while loop and main vi triggers an event every ~150ms. Which is to be handled in the **subvi**. This is the part which is not happening. I can see the **main vi's control** getting updated but the event(if generated) is not handled by the **subvi**. I'm using control's `property node->Value(signalling)` to change the value as well as trigger the event. What can be the possible cause?

*note: the control (whose value is changed), event handler are the same as in the first phase.*

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: please post the code...

Comment: @CharlesB i found the problem . the subsequent events were not being handled because the loop in which the event handler ran looped **once**i.e the initial condition was itself false so the loop only ran once. this loop was controlled by stop if true. it had to be continue if true. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem . 
the subsequent events were not being handled because the loop in which the event handler ran looped **once**
i.e the initial condition was itself false so the loop only ran once. 
this loop was controlled by `stop if true`. it had to be `continue if true`.
the boolean variable that controlled this loop was `true`. this should have been my first clue.